# is there a hidden whitespace element in hash?

Tags: perl

Playing with Hash I came across the following output, not sure why this is. Is there a embedded whitespace in hash by default?

```
#! /usr/bin/perl
# playwhash
use warnings;
use strict;

my %normal = ("Tom ","5'3","Peter ","5'11","John " ,"5'7",);
foreach (1..6) {
    print each %normal, "\n";
    }
```

The output looks like

```
Peter 5'11
Tom 5'3
John 5'7

Peter 5'11
Tom 5'3
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

From the [docs on each function](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/each.html):

> After each has returned all entries from the hash or array, the next call to each returns the empty list in list context and undef in scalar context; the next call following that one restarts iteration.

So, after third iteration `each` just returns an empty list to show that there are no more elements in hash. Next calls return hash entries from the beginning.

Comment: Sorry. I should have checked perldoc for it first. Thank you for pointing it out.

Answer (score 2):

The `each` returns the key and value, so the number of iterations is not 6 (this is the sum of keys + values). This is a common use of `each`:

```
while( ($key, $value) = each %normal ) {
   print "$key  =>  $value\n";
}
```

or just for printing perl structures:

```
use Data::Dump;
my %normal = ("Tom ","5'3","Peter ","5'11","John " ,"5'7",);
dd %normal;
```